# how to prevent uploading .htaccess file with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

In order to have a safe upload page. we need to prevent uploading any executable file like: `php`, `asp` using something like this:

```
<Files *.php>
Deny from All
</Files>
```

But what if someone tries to upload a `.htaccess` file?
How can prevent uploading `.htaccess` files in htaccess?

**EDIT**
anyone can change headers to upload a `php` file or `asp` or whatever, including `.htaccess`

well, this is a good looking and secure code:

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILE['file']);
$valid = ['jpg','png','gif'];
if(in_array($extension,$valid))
    // ok. upload file
else
    // something is wrong.
```

but I can rename a `php` file to a `test.jpg` file and upload it, it's a valid jpg file and my script will allow it to upload, now, I change headers and change `test.jpg` to `test.php` file, and assume this test.php file is a shell file.... .

Comment: `.htaccess` was not made to prevent people from uploading files into your server/account. That should be dealt on your upload code and by securing your server to prevent loose things. You can easily verify if a file being uploaded ends with `.php` you can check the headers, etc. The rule you current have on your question will disallow every single person to access any files ending with `.php` on your hosting.

Comment: this not works when I change headers... I can easily upload php files even programmer of a website already checks any kind of extensions to prevent or allow. and you can do that with Http_Live_Headers yourself.

Comment: Post your code then so we can see what is wrong.

Comment: just check the $_FILES["fileinputname"]["name"] content to see what the filename is, if its `.htaccess` do not do a `move_uploaded_file`, use fileinfo to check the files actual mime type

Comment: I think mime-type is also checks from extension.

Comment: Use [**`getimagesize`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), etc, there are also other ways but yours is definitively not safe. [Read more here...](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/32853)

Comment: “[…] I change headers and change `test.jpg` to `test.php` file […]” – Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Gumbo , take a look at this link. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/

Comment: @Pars But you’re checking the file name extension, don’t you?

Comment: yes, as you see in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your question should be (How to validate an image)

This is one of the functions of  [exif_imagetype()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

> exif_imagetype — Determine the type of an image

And then compare the what that function will return to you as a type of the image with your white list images types.

> When a correct signature is found, the appropriate constant value will
> be returned otherwise the return value is FALSE. The return value is
> the same value that getimagesize() returns in index 2 but
> exif_imagetype() is much faster.

Sample usage:

```
if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    echo 'The picture is not a gif';
}
```

If you would like to allow multiple types, then include them into an array and check if the retured type exists in that array.

---

Another solution would be to use [`getimagesize()`](http://www.php.net/getimagesize) which returns zeros for size on non-images.

---

Aside note: have all images uploaded into a separate sub directory rather than a directory that contains some php files or any other code files.

---

---

**Update:**

Based on your comment. If you want to allow the user to upload whatever kinds of files they wish to [not only images], then validating against all kind of files would seem endless. Therefore if I were to do that, I would mask the file and make it not executable. But if you have a set of allowed files to be uploaded, then I recommend you list it somewhere and validate against it.

1.**Method 1**: rename the file and/or change it's extension to something else.
The server is configured only to execute a set of known types of files.
If the user choose to upload `file.php` then save that file name into the db, and rename the actual file's name to `file_[timestamp][user_id][randome_code]` for example and save the new name to the db as well. And then whenever the user requests that file, just rename it to it's original name and allow him/her to download.

2.**Method 2**: compress the file into .zip. It won't be executable able that way.

Comment: it's not about image, I just made an example for images, a file can be doc, pdf, zip, image, etc...